# How to float one div and stack two remaining divs with 100% width?

Tags: css, css-float

I know how to float divs and how to stack divs. But I can't get both of them together right now.
What I need is this:

```
#########################################
#         #         #first_row          #
# #brand  ###############################
#         #        #second_row          #
#########################################
```

They lay all in my #header container with the following specs:

```
#header {
 width: 100%;
}

#brand {
 float:left;
 width: 300px;
}

#first_row, #second_row {
 width:100%
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

```css
#header {
 width: 100%;
}
#brand, #first_row, #second_row {
 float:left;
}
#brand {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
}
#first_row, #second_row {
 width: calc(100% - 300px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="header">
  <div id="brand">
   Brand
  </div>
  <div id="first_row">
   First row
  </div>
  <div id="second_row">
   Second row
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sure. Just give **#brand** a width of 30% (or something else) and **#first_row, #second_row** a width of 70%.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your first:row and second:row into a div with float:left and it will work:

```
<div id="header">

</div>
<div id="brand">
    brand
    <br/>
    brand
</div>
<div id="rows">
    <div id="first_row">First row</div>
    <div id="second_row">second row</div>

</div>
```

here you have an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/6sbfnc07/)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear at first. I need a width of 100% of the remaining space for the rows.

Comment: You can use width:calc(100% - 300px);  here updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6sbfnc07/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap #first_row and #second_row in a div and float it left as well. Like:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="brand">Brand</div>
    <div style="float:left">
        <div id="first_row">First row</div>
        <div id="second_row">Second row</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another container, floating right, then your div inside will be stacked :

```
<div id='header' class='floating-container'>
    <div class='left'>Brand</div>
    <div class='right'>
        <div class='first-row'>First Row</div>
        <div class='second-row'>Second Row</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bkwa06su/)

EDIT : if you do not want to fix the size of the right column, just do not :

[Second demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bkwa06su/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the media object:

http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/

B